# Adding dictionary values to a list?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following:

```
 list_of_values = []    
 x = { 'key1': 1, 'key2': 2, 'key3': 3 }
```

How can I iterate through the dictionary and append one of those values into that list? What if I only want to append the value of 'key2'.

Comment: Why would you iterate if you're interested in a specific key? Just do a lookup.

Comment: you can iterate over dic by using  : 
for k,v in x.items() :
(in this loop give ur requirement for appending and append to list_of_values)
list_of_values.append(v)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to append a specific set of values you don't need to iterate through the dictionary can simply add it to the list

```
list_of_values.append(x["key2"])
```

However, if you insist on iterating through the dictionary you can iterate through the key value pairs:

```
for key, value in x.items():
   if key == "key2":
      list_of_values.append(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to iterate over the dictionary I would suggest using list comprehensions and thereby creating a new list and inserting `'key2'` :

```
list_of_values = [x[key] for key in x if key == 'key2']
```

because that can be easily extended to search for multiple keywords:

```
keys_to_add = ['key2'] # Add the other keys to that list.
list_of_values  = [x[key] for key in x if key in keys_to_add]
```

That has the simple advantage that you create your result in one step and don't need to append multiple times. After you are finished iterating over the dictionary you can append the list, just to make it interesting, you can do it without `append` by just adding the new list to the older one:

```
list_of_values += [x[key] for key in x if key in keys_to_add]
```

Notice how I add them in-place with `+=` which is exactly equivalent to calling `list_of_values.append(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
list_of_values = []    
x = { 'key1': 1, 'key2': 2, 'key3': 3 }
list_of_values.append(x['key2'])
```